# Mockup screens using Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mockups

In one of the presentation i heard today, the presenter mentioned that they used Bootstrap to build/convert Mock-up screens to working HTML pages. I didn't get a chance to ask more details on it.

Could anyone provide any pointers on Bootstrap for this purpose ?

Comment: There you go: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) provides such nice styling "out of the box" that often just including* the Bootstrap assets will make an otherwise plain, but semantically correct, HTML document much more attractive.

There is a school of thought that too much polish in a mockup will bog-down design sessions because the customer will be too concerned about the perfect shade of blue. For this reason, many tools produce mock-ups that look like cartoons and white-board drawings. So the pro's and con's of applying Bootstrap-level polish are worth considering.

*--one of the more simple ways to "include" these assets in your mockup is via a CDN. See http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/ for an example.

Comment: thank you for the response.   >>many tools produce mock-ups that look like cartoons and white-board drawings<< is there any such tool that you would recommend ?

Comment: @yathirigan: sorry, no, I haven't used any enough to recommend one over another. But others have covered this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528769/best-web-app-for-creating-screen-mockups

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/download/) tool with [Bootstrap template](https://mockupstogo.mybalsamiq.com/projects/web/Bootstrap) for, or some web-based interface building tools such as [Jetstrap](https://jetstrap.com/plans) or [Divshot](http://www.divshot.com/) or [BootstrapDesigner](http://www.bootstrapdesigner.com/) seems this is the cheapest one